# Adobe AIR desktop application: How to delete cache?

Tags: caching, air, adobe, flex3

We are developing an Adobe AIR desktop application. There are login and logout buttons. Here we login to a remote server through opensso and after finishing all the operations we logout. But if we don't close the application, and in the same window if we login again as a different user, we are observing some anomalies. Some features of the previous user is retained in the application. But if we totally close the app, launch it again and then login as a different user, it's working properly.

So we are thinking of clearing the cache during logout. Can you please show me how to delete the cache of the Adobe Air application? It should work in all the windows versions, like Windows 7, Windows 10.

Thanks
Nirmalya